# Date Converting in R

Tags: r, date

In my dataframe that contains data pasted from the Excel file in R, the date format (taking the element in the first row & 11th column as an example) is the following:

```
data_agg[[1,11]]
[1] "2018-03-16 UTC"
```

I do want to convert the date format to "2018-03-16" without UTC. So, I wrote the following code to achieve that:

```
as.Date(data_agg[[1,11]])
[1] "2018-03-16"
```

As of now this works out perfectly. And I wanted to assign this new date format to the original place in my data frame. So I have the following code:

```
> data_agg[[1,11]] <- as.Date(data_agg[[1,11]])
> data_agg[[1,11]]
[1] "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC"
```

As you can see from above, after I converted the date format and reassign, somehow the element value changed to "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC". Can anyone shed some light on what is going on with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, dates and times are just numbers under the hood. The way that R knows to interpret them as dates/times is through an attribute attached to the variable:

```
> d <- Sys.Date()
> attributes(d)
$class
[1] "Date"
```

Now, where it gets funky, is that when you put these objects in vectors, the `class` attribute is attached to the vector itself, not to each element of the vector. This means that you cannot have differently-typed numeric values in the same vector.

If you want to replace all elements of a column in a data frame with their date equivalent, you can cast and assign the whole column at once:

```
> data_agg[,11] <- as.Date(data_agg[,11])
```

**Edit:** If what you really want is to have a bunch of date-representing strings in a vector along with other strings, then just convert your strings to dates and then back again:

```
> data_agg[[1,11]] <- as.character(as.Date(data_agg[[1,11]]))
```

or, if the string `" UTC"` doesn't show up in any of your other strings, you can use a direct string replacement function, like @shum suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did think of assigning the whole column at once. However, the 11th column happen to contain other character strings, such as "Yes", and if I were to use the same date conversion, it'd yield error message. Can you suggest another method under this circumstance? Thanks!

Comment: So you want to store them as strings, not as dates?